# Unwanted NULL values in MySQL query results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL table

tbl_pet_types:

```
+----------+-------------+
| pet      | type        |
+----------+-------------+
| cat      | mammal      |
| dog      | mammal      |
| goldfish | fish        |
| goldfish | seacreature |
| snake    | reptile     |
+----------+-------------+
```

I have this query to select a frog and its types:

```
SELECT types.pet,
group_concat(types.type separator ', ') AS type
FROM tbl_pet_types types
WHERE types.pet IN ('frog', 'mouse', 'goldfish');
```

Since frog and mouse are not the tbl_pet_types, the results returned are:

```
+----------+-------------------+
| pet      | type              |
+----------+-------------------+
| goldfish | fish, seacreature |
+----------+-------------------+
```

But I want:

```
+----------+------------------+
| pet      | type             |
+==========+==================+
| frog     | NULL             |
+----------+------------------+
| mouse    | NULL             |
+----------+------------------+
| goldfish | fish,seacreature |
+----------+------------------+
```

How can I alter my query to get the results I want?

Comment: try IFNULL() function

Answer (score 1):

Use the [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function to specify a default value if `types.pet` is `null`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(types.pet, 'frog'),
GROUP_CONCAT(types.type separator ', ') AS type
FROM tbl_pet_types types
WHERE types.pet='frog';
```

Comment: thank you for this answer. I made some edits to my original question. See above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, as frog doesn't appear in tbl_pet_types you need to `INSERT` it into the table

```
INSERT INTO tbl_pet_types (pet, type)
VALUES ('frog', NULL);
```

Then re-run your query

Answer (score 0):

You must do, after a SELECT query check, an INSERT INTO tbl_pet_types (pet, type) VALUES ('frog', NULL);

SELECT only retrieve data that is already set into database!

You can check more here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp